# Why doesn't XLSXWRITER create a file once my Kivy app is compliled into an APK?

Tags: python, apk, kivy, xlsxwriter

XLSXWRITER works on my Mac computer when I run my kivy app and successfully creates an XLSX file.

Unfortunately once I compile the apk using buildozer the "Export" button I made doesn't create the XLSX.

No crash occurs, I just can't find the XLSX that should have been created. My theory is that the spreadsheet is created but 'lives' within the APK Package.

Please help me to create XLSX using Kivy on android!
* Python 2.7.15
* Kivy 1.9.1
* Android Phone

Comment: You need to post your code for us to understand what is happening. That said, you need `android.permissions = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`in your `buildozer.spec` file. And you need to carefully set the path of the file you want to write. Android likes to write files in an application directory that you cannot access, so that may be where your missing file is written.

Comment: John Anderson, it works! You are a gentleman and a scholar!

Comment: @theKalkulator please post an answer for your question. It will be useful for community and for Anoop in particular

Answer (score 1):

With an aid from @"John Anderson", the solution lies in the AndroidManifest.xml file, where one can simply "comment out" using the html comments "". At the bottom one can find the list of permissions that the app may or may not require, and can thereby comment out unnecessary permissions like "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".